# .htaccess Rewrites: add .html to wordpress posts and pages

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to change wordpress links from static links to .html extensions and use 301 redirect to the new links because i don't want to lose the website pages at search engines

Ex : example.com/page-name > example.com/page-name.html 
   : example.com/post-name > example.com/post-name.html

My code in ROOT htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Ok, sounds like a project where you will learn a lot. _Or did you have any question here_?

Comment: Why do you want `.html` extensions in the first place? Changing URL structure in WordPress is a pain because there are so many places full URLs (including scheme and domain!) are hard-coded into the settings and content.